# Extract first word after split() method in pandas column

Tags: string, pandas

I have a df column of sentences (df.sentence) like below:

```
sentence 
His name is Paul. He's in jail.
Her name is Allison. She's a doctor.
He is named Steve. He's an engineer.
```

etc.

Currently, I have a loop set up as follows to extract the names:

```
for i in range(len(df.sentence):
  if 'name is' in df['sentence'][i]:
    name = re.findall(r'(?<=name is\s)[a-z]+',str(df['sentence'][i]),re.I)
```

This however does not work. Or I just may need help setting the regex up properly.

UPDATED (does not output correctly):

```
for i in range(len(df)):
  if '[name is|named]' in df['sentence'][i]:
    name = df.sentence.i.str.extract('[name is|named]\s(.*?)(?=\.|\s)')
  else:
    pass
```

Comment: You want to extract the names? You'll need some basic idea of the pattern, for instance is it just the single word following `[His\Her] name is`, or everything before the period?

Comment: @ALollz, same pattern. The word directly after the string 'name is'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a *lookbehind assertion*:

```
df.str.extract(r'(?<= name is |is named )(\w+)')
```

Output:

```
         0
0     Paul
1  Allison
2    Steve
```

Comment: Didn't need the '?<=', but exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: @user10939484 It will still work, but then you'll have two columns (unless you're okay with that)

Answer (score 0):

If all the lines in this column is in same format (as fourth word of interest) then directly fetch index 4.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the case. IF the string (name is or named) is located in the sentence, then I'd like to extract the word directly after.